# How can I permanently divide / separate files, folders, and shortcuts on Windows 7 desktop?

Tags: windows-7, icons, desktop-customization

Basically I want to devote a flexible, visibly divided fraction of my screen to each type of icon visible on the Desktop (files, folders, shortcuts).

What will I (or someone much more skilled than I am) have to do to make this happen? Seems like something a custom skin would do, but I just want to do this one thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are looking for:  [Stardock Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/).  Its not free, but its pretty cheap.  I know several people who swear by it...

From their website:

```
A one-of-a-kind tool
Create "fences" on your desktop to organize icons
Hide and show your desktop icons with a click
Mirror your folders' contents on the desktop
Have new desktop icons automatically sorted into an appropriate "fence"
```

Comment: :O THAT LOOKS PERFECT!  
<br/>
Actually, even better than what I was asking for. Thanks!